# ServiceStack with shared hosting: SecurityException and ReflectionPermission

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

I'm facing following problem. I've got Service Stack-based webservice which I want have on shared hosting. When deploying there and trying to open an url I'm getting following error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +34
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Module m,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +243
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type
>   returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Module m, Boolean skipVisibility)
>   +48    ServiceStack.Text.ReflectionExtensions.GetConstructorMethodToCache(Type
>   type) +586
>   ServiceStack.Text.ReflectionExtensions.GetConstructorMethod(Type type)
>   +68    ServiceStack.Text.ReflectionExtensions.CreateInstance(Type type) +8
>   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.RegisterNServiceExecutor(Type
>   requestType, Type serviceType, ITypeFactory serviceFactoryFn) +123
>   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.RegisterNService(ITypeFactory
>   serviceFactoryFn, Type serviceType) +287
>   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.Register(ITypeFactory
>   serviceFactoryFn) +96
>   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceManager.Init() +50
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostBase.Init() +43
>   DarkMindFx.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +571

So it seems like ServiceStack cannot perform the reflaction.
I've also tried to

```html
<securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

to web.config but as the result hosting returns me an error with this line in web.config. 
Does anyone ever faced such issue? Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: OK, I have figured out how to make it working. It looks like the poblem was in ServiceStack - first I had version 4.0, but then removed and installed 3.9.71. It seems like I didn't manage to do it correctly and there was some kind of mixture of libraries and packages in my project. So when I've implemented a web app from the scrath everything became rainbows and unicorns.

Answer (score 1):

The SecurityException is because [GoDaddy doesn't support full trust ASP.NET hosting](http://forums.asp.net/t/1667721.aspx?Godaddy%20Medium%20trust%20Issues). You can try requesting their support to enable it for your site, otherwise you would need to use a different hosting provider.